# how to apply constraints on Django field within the instances associated with the user

Tags: django, django-models

I am making a todo app for practice, the functionality I want to achieve is that, when a user create a task,Only the time field should be unique about all of his tasks, I have done (unique=True) In the time field in model but that make it unique all over the database, but I want it to be unique only with the tasks associated with the user.
the view is below:

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def home(request):
    tasks = Task.objects.filter(name__username=request.user.username)

    form = TaskForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TaskForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            obj.name = request.user
            obj.save()
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            print(request.POST)
            print(request.user.username)
            messages.warning(request, 'Invalid Data!')
            return redirect('home')

    context = {'tasks' : tasks}
    return render(request, 'task/home.html', context)
```

task model:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    choices = (
        ('Completed', 'Completed'),
        ('In Complete', 'In Complete'),
    )
    name = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    task = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, blank=False)
    time = models.TimeField(auto_now_add=False, blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=choices, null=True, blank=False)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.task
    
    def get_task_author_profile(self):
        return reverse('profile')
```

as you can see, I want to show the task that the logged in user has added.

the form is:

```
class TaskForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ['name']
```

the functionality I talked about above, I tried to achieve through view:

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def home(request):
    tasks = Task.objects.filter(name__username=request.user.username)
    time = []
    for task in tasks:
        time.append(task['time'])
    form = TaskForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TaskForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid() and form.cleaned_data['time'] != time:
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            obj.name = request.user
            obj.save()
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            print(request.POST)
            print(request.user.username)
            messages.warning(request, 'Invalid Data!')
            return redirect('home')

    context = {'tasks' : tasks}
    return render(request, 'task/home.html', context)
```

but that gave an error:  `TypeError: 'Task' object is not subscriptable`
I know its not right, but how can I achieve it, does Django have anything that can provide such fuctionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is coming from here:

```
for task in tasks:
    time.append(task['time'])  #<--
```

Here if you want to use access time, you need to use `task.time` because `task` is an object.

Also need to fix another thing in your exisiting code to make it work, because `time` is a list:

```
if form.is_valid() and form.cleaned_data['time'] in time:  
#                                                ^^^
```

BTW, you don't need to make it that complicated, you can add Database level constraint from the model to make the times unique for a specific user. Also, use `DateTime` field for that. You can use [`unique_togather`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/options/#unique-together) for that:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    choices = (
        ('Completed', 'Completed'),
        ('In Complete', 'In Complete'),
    )
    name = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    task = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, blank=False)
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=choices, null=True, blank=False)
    
    class Meta:
        unique_togather = ['name', 'time']
```